# How to transform a data.frame of transactions data to sequence data in R?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of transactions in the following format:

```
item   transactionID  customerID
 A           1            1
 B           1            1
 B           2            2
 C           3            1
 A           4            3
```

I want to convert it to the following format and store it in a text file to later analyze it using arulesSequences package:

```
CustomerID  SequenceID   Size   items
    1            1        2     {A,B}
    1            2        1      {C}
    2            1        1      {B}
    3            1        1      {A}
```

I am looking for the best way to transform this data. Note that for each customer we might have more than one transactions and each transaction may contain more than one items. Thanks.

Comment: use dcast in reshape package

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(customerID, transactionID) %>% 
summarise(Size = length(item), items = paste(item, collapse=",")) %>%
group_by(customerID) %>% 
mutate(items = paste0("{",items,"}"), transactionID = row_number())

Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: customerID

  customerID transactionID Size items
1          1             1    2 {A,B}
2          1             2    1   {C}
3          2             1    1   {B}
4          3             1    1   {A}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base solution with `aggregate`:

```
with( inp, aggregate(item, 
                     list(transactionID =transactionID, customerID =customerID), 
                     function(item) c(Size=length(item), 
                                      items=paste0("{",paste0(item,collapse=","), "}"))))

  transactionID customerID x.Size x.items
1             1          1      2   {A,B}
2             3          1      1     {C}
3             2          2      1     {B}
4             4          3      1     {A}
```